# CSS наложить див на див

Tags: html, css

Стоит задача: создать див класс, в качестве фона - изображение, высота его зависит от содержимого. Назову этот блок - Основной.
Далее: второй див класс черного цвета с полупрозрачностью для затемнения основного блока. Назову его - Затемнение.
Наложить у меня получилось, но вот проблема - затемняется и текст который находится внутри Основного блока.
Я пробовал текст вписывать внутрь блока Затемнения, но в данном случае Основной блок не растягивается по высоте содержимого.
Целый день ищу, думаю как бы решить эту проблему. Нужно чтобы и текст был в самом верхнем слое и изображение фоновое затемненное.
Вот что сейчас:

```
 .main {
 background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
 z-index: 1;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 position: relative;
 color: white;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: center;
  }

 .blackout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   z-index: 10;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100% ;
     }


 <div class="main">
 <div class="blackout"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Евгений вы может быть ответите на мой комментарий в вашем прошлом вопросе ?

Comment: Не видел. Извините. Сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: двое ответили - так и не понял в чём здесь фишка ?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю какую роль выполняет именно в данном случае :before? Создаёт дополнительный слой поверх изображения?

Comment: before/after работают только с пустым/заполненным content="" и выполняют роль псевдоэлемента ...т.е другими словами это обычный блок [и в codepen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/LqQdvo) я показал как это выглядит но можно его стилизовать и пользоваться им как обычным div

Comment: То есть, этот блок накладывается поверх изображения?

Comment: да - верно, ты смотрел кодепен ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский хороший понятный codepen получился :-)

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
.bg {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url('https://www.popsci.com/sites/popsci.com/files/styles/1000_1x_/public/images/2018/06/edinburgh_meadows_2008_middle_meadow_walk_by_catharine_ward_thompson.jpg?itok=ysmDaSjD&fc=50,50');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.bg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="content">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А можете вкратце объяснить пожалуйста, что означает :before и конкретно пустой content = ' ';    Это значит что это применяется ко всему содержимому?

Comment: В данном случае псевдоэлемент используется, чтобы разметку html сделать чище, также псевдоэлемент без content: ""; работать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main {
  background-image: url('https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

p {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Учимся работать с псевдоэлементами</p>
  <p>Учимся работать с псевдоэлементами</p>
  <p>Учимся работать с псевдоэлементами</p>
  <p>Учимся работать с псевдоэлементами</p>
  <p>Учимся работать с псевдоэлементами</p>
  <p>Учимся работать с псевдоэлементами</p>
  <p>Учимся работать с псевдоэлементами</p>
</div>
```

Вариант без z-index

Comment: А если вместо <p> будет что-то другое? И что означает пустой content: " ";            ?

Comment: [content:'';](http://htmlbook.ru/css/content) и [:before\:after](http://htmlbook.ru/css/before) . Вместо p что хотите то и делайте, это лишь пример. главное не забудьте элементу который будет вместо р поставить position relative

Comment: Не понимаю, почему тогда текст сверху наложенный не стал прозрачным? Оно ведь к родителю применялось

Comment: не понимаю о чём вы сейчас говорите.... :-(

Comment: before: в данном случае создал дополнительный слой? или я что-то не так понял?